# XTSE1650: net.sf.saxon.trans.LicenseException: Requested feature (xsl:import-schema) requires Saxon-EE

Tags: saxon

I use java and saxonee-9.5.1.6.jar included build path , when run, getting these errors at different times.

Error at xsl:import-schema on line 6 column 169 of stylesheet.xslt:
  XTSE1650: net.sf.saxon.trans.LicenseException: Requested feature (xsl:import-schema)
  requires Saxon-EE

Error on line 1 column 1 
  SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: Content is not allowed in prolog.
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.

I open .xslt file in hex editor and dont see any different character at the beginning AND
I use transformerfactory in a different project but any error I get.

Comment: It's not possible to explain why you are getting an error if you don't tell us what you are doing (beyond the fact that you "use Java"). The first error could be, for example, because you used "new Processor(false)" rather than "new Processor(true)" when starting Saxon, but it could have any number of other possible causes; there's no way of knowing from the information supplied. The second error tells us two things: (a) your stylesheet isn't well-formed XML, and (b) you are trying to compile it using JAXP interfaces. Again, without seeing your code or your stylesheet, we can't tell you more.

Answer (score 0):

Check what the implementation class of tFactory is. My guess is it is probably `net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl` - which is basically the Saxon-HE version.

When you use JAXP like this, you're very exposed to configuration problems, because it loads whatever it finds sitting around on the classpath, or is affected by system property settings which could be set in parts of the application you know nothing about.

If your application depends on particular features, it's best to load a specific TransformerFactory, e.g. tFactory = new com.saxonica.config.EnterpriseTransformerFactory().

I don't know whether your stylesheet expects the source document to be validated against the schema, but it it does, note that this isn't automatic: you can set properties on the factory to make it happen.

I would recommend using Saxon's s9api interface rather than JAXP for this kind of thing. The JAXP interface was designed for XSLT 1.0, and it's a real stretch to use it for some of the new 2.0 features like schema-awareness: it can be done, but you keep running into limitations.